# UITableView header clipping issue

Tags: objective-c, tableview, clipping

I am having a visual issue with the UITableView, the header of the table view appears correctly on the 5,4,4s and 3 iPhones but with the 5s, 6, 6+ there is a clipping issue. Does anyone know what the problem might be?  images below.

Issue 5S + 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eckmvddmwspugdk/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2002.20.49.png?dl=0

Non Issue 4S and 5
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e102s5iojk05kd6/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2002.20.02.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jiqw3o4f0tzfou/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2002.18.30.png?dl=0

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Excercises Queued Up";
}

-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  30.0;
}
```

These two functions are overriden as well

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the viewForHeaderInSection and heightForHeaderInSection code here. And even the xib of the header view if any.

Comment: Done, there is no xib for the header view.

Comment: I actually fixed it removing this though why would that happen in that case? 
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  30.0;
}

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it removing this though why would that happen in that case? -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return 30.0; } – and it worked